# How to sketch a particle in 3D space

Tags: vectors, graphing-functions

~r(t) =

```
  `Acosh(wt)
   Bsinh(wt)
   C`
```

How would I sketch this particle?

My original idea was writing it as x^2/A^2 - y^2/B^2 + z = 1 + c, which gives a hyperbola.

Because x = acosh(wt) , y = bsinh(wt) and z = c. Then I used hyperbolic identities.

Is this idea right? As I end up with a graph in 2D?

Comment: The particles movement occurs within $2$D space (the plane $z=c$) hence one can just use a $2$D sketch of a hyperbola as you supposed.

Comment: Thank you. If I drew a hyperbola like this where would it cross the x axis? As the c makes it so it no longer crosses at a and -a. From desmos it doesn't appear to cross at -a-c and a+c.

Comment: It crosses the $x$ axis at the same coordinate as the $2$D plot except the $z$ coordinate is equal to $c$ instead of $0$.

Comment: Thank you, I get it now.

Comment: Having the x makes it not a hyperbola though. x^2/A^2 - y^2/B^2 + z = 1 + c. Do I need to take away the z and c. Then sketch x^2/A^2 - y^2/B^2 = 1?